# Hosting a WCF service in an unmanaged c++ application

Tags: wcf, unmanaged, host

I have the following setup

1. a legacy MFC app written in native vc++.
2. a mixed mode dll bridge that has a natvie proxy for 2 managed classes, a sender and a receiver.
3. a managed class "AsyncSender" that sends out soap messages asynchronously for the MFC
4. a WCF service that receives the responses and passes them off to MFC app

WCF service is being self hosted. the problem is the return messages are not reaching the WCF service.when I host the service using a console app, they are though. this is happening when I am hosting the WCF service inside a thread in the CLR hosted by MFC.

I tried the following with no luck.

- created a new thread for running the wcf service.
- set the attrbiute "usesynchronizationcontext" to false.

I am not using any config files. just doing everything in code. pretty basic. it works when hosted in a separate process. but doesn't when hosted in the setup described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006507/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-native-c-program